# How can I divide grouped array-object by length?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following data retrieved from a database

```
var members = [
  { "name" : "a", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" },
  { "name" : "b", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" },
  { "name" : "c", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" },
  { "name" : "d", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" },
  { "name" : "e", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" },
  { "name" : "f", "department_id" : 2, "department_name" : "bbb" },
  { "name" : "g", "department_id" : 2, "department_name" : "bbb" }
];
```

The first step is to group this data by department name.

```
var groupedMembers = _.groupBy(members, "department_name");

↓

{
  "aaa" : [
    { "name" : "a", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" },
    { "name" : "b", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" },
    { "name" : "c", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" },
    { "name" : "d", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" },
    { "name" : "e", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" }
  ],
  "bbb" : [
    { "name" : "f", "department_id" : 2, "department_name" : "bbb" },
    { "name" : "g", "department_id" : 2, "department_name" : "bbb" }
  ]
}
```

From this state, I want to further split the object into every three objects.

Ideally, I would like the array to be formatted in the following way

```
var expected = {
  "aaa1" : [
    { "name" : "a", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" },
    { "name" : "b", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" },
    { "name" : "c", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" }
  ],
  "aaa2" : [
    { "name" : "d", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" },
    { "name" : "e", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" }
  ],
  "bbb" : [
    { "name" : "f", "department_id" : 2, "department_name" : "bbb" },
    { "name" : "g", "department_id" : 2, "department_name" : "bbb" }
  ]
};
```

Can I solve that by using Underscore.js or lodash.js?
If it's not too difficult, you can use other libraries or pure javascript implementations.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use pure javascript to implement.

```
var groupedMembers = {
  "aaa" : [
    { "name" : "a", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" },
    { "name" : "b", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" },
    { "name" : "c", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" },
    { "name" : "d", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" },
    { "name" : "e", "department_id" : 1, "department_name" : "aaa" }
  ],
  "bbb" : [
    { "name" : "f", "department_id" : 2, "department_name" : "bbb" },
    { "name" : "g", "department_id" : 2, "department_name" : "bbb" }
  ]
}

var splitByThree = {}

for (const key in groupedMembers) {
  if (groupedMembers[key].length <= 3) {
    splitByThree[key] = groupedMembers[key]
  }
  else {
    for (var i=0, j=groupedMembers[key].length; i<j; i+=3) {
      splitByThree[key + (i+3)/3] = groupedMembers[key].slice(i, i+3);
    }
  }
}
```

Then splitByThree is your expected result.